# Is there a single cell RNAseq equivalent of GTEx or TCGA?

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, single-cell, gtex

Or do I need to find individual studies and obtain data the long way!

Comment: Does the question read as "Is there a database of Human scRNA seq data?"? I think https://bgee.org/ contains some scRNA seq data, probably other databases too. Did you try to simply google it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most well-known scRNA dataset that is similar to GTEx in the Human Cell Atlas (https://www.humancellatlas.org). It is pretty much still ongoing but there are some preliminary data.